# Work done by a Photovoltaic cell

Tags: energy-conservation, solar-cells

Is the electrical work done a Photovoltaic cell equal to the energy of the photon incident upon the cell? (Assuming energy is not lost/gained due to other interactions)

If we do not discard other interactions, what could cause the energy loss during the photovoltaic process?

Comment: Any energy above the band gap basically turns into heat.

Comment: @JonCuster To clarify, would this be energy above the conduction band?

Comment: Yes, electrons thermalize down to the bottom of the band quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

The Efficiency of a Photovoltaic cell is a measure of the power you get from the cell compared to the power incident on it:

$$Efficiency= \frac{P_{out}}{P_{in}}$$

As such it is partly dependent on the energy of the photons coming in.

However the work done is not exactly equal to the energy of the incident photon, for the reason pointed out by the commenter (electron thermalisation), and there are other resistances within the material itself, which can be caused by grain boundaries, material faults, *etc.* All these serve to reduce the amount of power (and therefore work you can do) from a cell. Defect energy levels that can be present can make unwanted recombination easier, reducing the number of electrons available for work, thus reducing the amount of work that can be done.

Two of the main causes of efficiency/energy loss from a solar cell are *series* resistance and *shunt* resistance. The first of these is caused simply by resistance to movement of charge in the material, the contacts used in the complete cell, and wires used to give a few examples. *Shunting* is caused by manufacturing defects (like poor grain boundaries) which gives the electron an alternate pathway, which isn't useful for what we would want it for - ideally a material would have a high shunt resistance.